# how to read two video files with open mp and opencv in vs 2010

Tags: c++, opencv, openmp

Can anyone explain to me how write a program to read two video files in parallel (make using of open mp)?

I have installed opencv linked with vs 2010, will it work with this configuration? I have written code to read the video file but it isn't working.

```
#pragma omp parallel sections num_threads(2)
{
#pragma omp section
{
pMOG= new BackgroundSubtractorMOG(); //MOG approach
// pMOG2= new BackgroundSubtractorMOG2(); //MOG2 approach

if(strcmp("test.avi", "-vid") == 1) {
//input data coming from a video
processVideo(argv[2]);
}
else if(strcmp(argv[1], "-img") == 0) {
//input data coming from a sequence of images
processImages(argv[2]);
}
else {
//error in reading input parameters
printf("Please, check the input parameters.");
printf("Exiting...");
// return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
//destroy GUI windows
destroyAllWindows();
// return EXIT_SUCCESS;
cout<<"I'm Venky"<<endl;
}
#pragma omp section
{
// pMOG= new BackgroundSubtractorMOG(); //MOG approach
pMOG2= new BackgroundSubtractorMOG2(); //MOG2 approach

if(strcmp("test8.avi", "-vid") == 1) {
//input data coming from a video
processVideo1(argv[2]);
}
else if(strcmp(argv[1], "-img") == 0) {
//input data coming from a sequence of images
processImages(argv[2]);
}
else {
//error in reading input parameters
printf("Please, check the input parameters.");
printf("Exiting...");
// return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
destroyAllWindows();
cout<<"I'm Venky"<<endl;
}
}
```

Comment: I'm getting run time error in the above code.

Comment: "Native' has exited with code 1 (0x1)" this is what i get once i run this code.

Comment: @jam thanks for responding, im doing background subtraction here i have to read the two video files parallel and the then i ll apply background subtraction algorithm, when i run the program sequentially i get output, but when i do it parallel i won't.